# VBA - Multiple Pivot Tables

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I work in a research institute and here, after we finish the research, a database is generated. From this database we need to make some crossings, for example, take the column that contains the sex and cross it with all the other columns in the spreadsheet, and for each crossing a new dynamic table would have to be created, all within the same spreadsheet, would it be possible to create a loop to go through the columns of the table and leave the Y axis fixed as sex? And as a counter use the identified column of the row.

I made a code to create a pivot table, but I couldn't include this loop or this way of going through all the columns.

```
Sub criarTabelaDinamica()

    Dim TabRange As Range
    Dim TabCache As PivotCache 'Tipo dados para Tabela Dinâmica
    Dim TabDin As PivotTable 'Tipo para Tabela Dinâmica

    Set TabRange = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion 'Associar intervalo com dados à variável

    'Define a fonte de dados da Tabela Dinâmica (que ficará em cache)
    Set TabCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches _
    .Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=TabRange)

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add 'Adiciona uma nova planilha, que se torna ativa
    ActiveSheet.Name = "TabelaDinamica"

    'Inserir a Tabela Dinâmica na planilha
    Set TabDin = TabCache.CreatePivotTable _
    (TableDestination:=Cells(1, 1), TableName:="TabelaDinamica1")

    'Adiciona o item aos títulos da linha
    TabDin.PivotFields("Ano").Orientation = xlRowField

    'Adiciona o item aos títulos da coluna
    TabDin.PivotFields("Região").Orientation = xlColumnField

    'Inserir dados agregados de Quantidade pela soma
    With TabDin.PivotFields("Quantidade")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Function = xlSum
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: If you follow the steps of [Askwizard](https://stackoverflow.com/help/askwizard) probably you can get more essential answers to your question

Answer (score 0):

Power Query can do it without VBA code.

- Create table: select a cell in source table, press <kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd> to create a table (ListObject)

[image]

- Load data into PQ: Data>From Table/Range

[image]

- Unpivot table: Select the first column in PQ, Transform > Unpivot Other Columns

[image]

- Change column name (optional): change `Attribute` to `TestX`

[image]

- Create PVT: Home > Close & Load to > PivotTable Report

[image]

- Update PVT layout: `Gender` is Rows field, `TestX` is Columns field, `Value` is Values field

[image]